# Java script: open one window print that one and than close it than open one new window

Tags: javascript, html

My requirement is, I need to open two window, but second window must open after first is print and close. is it possible?

but second window open with first window at a same time.

HTML/JSP code
Print

JAVA SCRIPT
function print(id) {

```
        var data=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
        var mywindow = window.open("",'TITLE','left=0,top=0,width=800,height=400,channelmode=no,titlebar=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no,directories=no,status=yes');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>TITLE</title>');
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>");

        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close(); 
        mywindow.focus(); 
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
        return true;
```

}

function popup() {
  var mysecondWindow = window.open("",'SecUtdOfficialWebsite','width=400,height=400');
}

Print

Comment: HTML code: from where java script function is triggered button type="button" onclick="if(print('test1')){popup();}" >Print</button

Comment: There's [afterprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/afterprint) event, but it's not widely supported.

Comment: okay. thanks! let me check if this work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  OpenFirstWindow()
})
var mywindow;
var mywindow2;
function OpenFirstWindow(){
 mywindow= window.open('')
          mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>TITLE</title><body onload="">');
mywindow.document.write("window 1");
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close()
  OpenSecondWindow();

}


function OpenSecondWindow(){
 mywindow2= window.open('')
          mywindow2.document.write('<html><head><title>TITLE</title><body >');
mywindow2.document.write("window 2");
        mywindow2.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow2.document.close(); 
  mywindow2.print();
  mywindow2.close()

}
```